# Как понять, где поставить тире, а где запятую?

Tags: запятые, тире

При наличии интонационной паузы между подлежащим и сказуемым и логическом ударении постановка тире возможна. Например: «Мы — молодая гвардия рабочих и крестьян», но в чем отличие от личного местоимения и приложения, которое отделяется запятой, например: Он, капитан пограничных войск, служил..?
Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 2):

В чём отличие сказуемого от приложения?

Ср. варианты:

*Он, капитан пограничных войск, служил...*

*Он — капитан пограничных войск, служил...*

В первом варианте то, что "он" является (или являлся) капитаном пограничных войск, несёт дополнительную, второстепенную информацию... Может быть, даже и известную ранее читателю. Здесь *капитан пограничных войск* — приложение, сказуемое же — *служил*.

Во втором — рассказывается о "нём": кем он является сейчас, где когда-то служил... И *капитан пограничных войск* и *служил* при этой пунктуации — сказуемые.

P.S.

И произносятся эти предложения при разном пунктуационном оформлении по-разному...